# shell script for below requirement

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

i have one file named access.log which is always being receiving data from server. so i need to copy the data of access.log file into several files   without effecting the data in any files. 
for example: if i execute the script, need to copy the data into another file (file name should be access_1.log)and access.log file should be truncated. and if i execute the same script 2nd time, the data should be copied to access_2.log file and access.log file should be truncated. so if run the file 10 times then need to created 10 files.
i have tried this below script but count values is not increasing in my code.so always getting same file name as access_1.log and data also we changing .

```
count=1
cp access.log access_$count.log
>access.log
count=`expr $count + 1`
```

please help me

Comment: Does your code have a loop?  If not, how will `count` ever change in a meaningful way?

Comment: Use command called logrotate.

Comment: i am new to scripting .please could you  write full code

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples) how to use it. You might as well move the file and then send HUP signal to daemon process writing to that log. `kill -HUP <pid>`

Comment: Can someone tell me why is this question getting -2 down voted?

Comment: @skr, it's asking for someone to provide the OP with code for their solution, not how to teach them to write a solution themselves. That's not what we do here -- StackOverflow is here to be a teaching resource and a canonical Q&A database, not a place where folks can go for "plz give me teh codhez" style questions.

Comment: @skr, on which point -- see the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how many times you run it the count value will be retained

```
LOCATION=/path/to/location
COUNT=`ls $LOCATION/access_*.log | wc -l`

COUNT=`expr $COUNT + 1`

cp $LOCATION/access.log $LOCATION/access_$COUNT.log
>$LOCATION/access.log
```

Comment: FYI -- `count=$(( count + 1 ))` is a much more efficient way to increment your counter. (And all-caps variable names are bad practice; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph). You're also propagating a bunch of quoting bugs into your answer. And see [BashFAQ #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) for best-practice guidance on counting files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if it works.

```
name='access'
    if [[ -e $name.log ]] ; then
        i=1
        while [[ -e $name_$i.log ]] ; do
            let i++
        done
        name=$name_$i
    fi
    cp -r /path/to/access.log  "$name".log
    cat /dev/null > /path/to/access.log
```

Comment: You are going to lose data this way. Whatever written between copy and truncate will be lost.

Comment: @MarekVitek how data will be lost this way as he already mentioned he want to truncate access.log file, can you suggest something better coz i think while rotating logs using script whatever written between copy and truncate will be lost anyhow.

Comment: Because he wants data to be moved/copied to another file. But items written to the log after copy and before truncate will not be copied to next numbered log.

Comment: @MarekVitek anything better than this because i think while rotating logs using script whatever written between copy and truncate will be lost anyhow.

Comment: it is better to do `mv access.log access1.log` and then `kill -HUP <pid>` where pid is pid of the daemon writing to the log file. It will force it to reread config and reopen files and thus start writing to new access.log

Comment: You are going to make your system miserable this way. Not only you will lose data. But you are doing unnecessary copy of data when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE_LOCATION=/path/to/file/
FILE_DEST=/second/path/

for count in $(seq 1 1000) ;do
    if [! -e ${FILE_DEST}access_${count}.log ];then
       cp ${FILE_LOCATION}access.log ${FILE_DEST}access_${count}.log
       exit 0
    fi
done
```

enjoy

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: `seq` isn't part of bash -- it's better to write `for ((i=0; i<=1000; i++)); do`, which will use only functionality built into the shell itself. And see http://shellcheck.net/, which will identify a number of quoting errors in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Put following content in myprocess.conf

```
   /var/log/access.log {
       rotate 10
       weekly
       postrotate
           /usr/bin/killall -HUP $myprocess
       endscript
   }
```

Then run logrotate command

```
logrotate --force $CONFIG_FILE
```

where `$CONFIG_FILE` is path to file with configuration you created. And $myprocess is name of the daemon writing to log. It will rotate log on weekly basis.
See /etc/logrotate.d directory for configurations you have already on your machine.

And if you are still not convinced and want to go with script for whatever reason then try this script.

```
last=`ls access_* | sort -n -k 1.8 -r| head -1 | sed -e 's/access_\([0-9]*\).log/\1/'`
(( last += 1 ))
mv access.log access_${last}.log
killall -HUP myprocess
```

The first line does following:

- lists all files starting with `access_`
- then it sorts numerically on 1st field 8th character
- then it takes only first line file with highest number
- then it extracts number from string access_123.log